# Bootstrap input box width

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="form-group">

    <label class="control-label col-md-3 text-right" for="jtd"> Job Title / Designation<sup>*</sup>:
    </label>

    <div class="col-md-7">
    <input type="text" name="jtd" id="jtd " />
    </div>
    </div>
```

I am facing a problem here. Thbe input box is not extending to 7 colunms width and it is coming very small. While the same code in another page is working fine. Can somebody plase help me with this problem.

Comment: I tried the same html as you have. It worked for me. Is there maybe any old css stuff which prevents that behaviour?

Comment: Just use code inspector embedded in your web browser to see what is controlling width of input field.